# Custom QGIS expression to filter atlas pages

Tags: qgis, filter, expression, atlas, qgis-custom-function

I want to filter my atlas pages based on a list returned by a custom function but it won't work.

This is my function:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def validZones(layerName, f1, feature, parent):

    lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
    if lyr is None:
        raise Exception("Layer not found: " + layerName)

    expr = QgsExpression("\"f_%s\" IS NOT NULL" % (f1))
    uniqueVal = set([feat['Zone'] for feat in lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))])
    okZone = list(uniqueVal)
    return okZone
```

And this is the filter expression:

```
"id_zone" IN validZones('myLayer', '32')
```

---

Trying to find the problem I've even tested the simplest function. Something like this:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def validZones(feature, parent):
    okZone = ['50','51']
    return okZone
```

With this filter expression:

```
"id_zone" IN validZones()
```

But it doesn't work either.

And as this works:

```
"id_zone" IN ('50','51')
```

I also tried using a tuple but to no avail:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def validZones(feature, parent):
    okokZone = ('50','51')
    return okZone
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The IN operator won't a accept a function no matter what I do. You must always pass a list like this (value1[, value2,...]). I decided to include the "id_zone" field as an argument to the function and evaluate it inside a for loop:  `for zone in okZone :
  if int(id_zone) == int(zone):
   return int(zone)` Anyway, if anyone has any good idea please share it!

Comment: You should consider posting your comment as an **answer** :)